# Bootstrap - Table Overlapping in Columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to work out why my columns are overlapping in bootstrap

- I've checked that my columns add up to 12
- After "row" class there is always a column class

I have added my full code in a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/exubnw4a/

[image: Problem]

As you can see , a lot of these values are getitng pushed together, when it should be 4 separate tables

Here is a shortened down version of my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <h1>LH5</h1>
                <table class="table">
                 table contents here
                </table>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <h1>LH5</h1>
                <table class="table">
                 table contents here
                </table>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <h1>LH5</h1>
                <table class="table">
                 table contents here
                </table>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <h1>LH5</h1>
                <table class="table">
                 table contents here
                </table>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there was a good comment, which is now removed, pointing out that your `<div class="row">` are not closed as you go from table to table. [tag soup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-soup) clean up is causing to seemingly not affect things, but it should be fixed by adding closing `</div>` where necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Your table contains more rows which take more width than the `25%` of `col-md-3` class. You can make use of `table-responsive` class in such cases.

[**SAMPLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/exubnw4a/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Starting at `md` (medium, around 992 pixels), the main 4 divs are shrinking to 25% due to `class="col-md-3"`.  Remove that and it will go back to desired 100% at all sizes.  See this screenshot showing how removing that causes it to work for the table on which it is removed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place 4 elements in 1 row, make sure that they are all inside the same Bootstrap "row" class. In your case, you have to put all your tables in one row instead of creating a new row for each table.